# Editing Summary Links Web Part on a publising Site in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, web-parts, publishing-site

I am trying to figure out how to change the title of a **Summary Links Web Part** in SharePoint 2013.
Below is an image of the summary links web part.  I would like the change the title "SUMMARY LINKS" to "BLAH" but can't figure it out for the life of me. 
This is probably very simple but I'm lost. I haven't found any controls to edit the title nor is there anything in source to change the title...Any ideas? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!!   I was missing the ability to edit the web part properties.  Looks like an IE11 bug.  Once I put IE in compatibility mode and or switched to using Chrome I had all the options I needed to updated the Summary Links title.